# Macro to Create Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Following is my data set in excel

```
COLUMN E    COLUMN K  COLUMN L  COLUMN M  COLUMN N
A3000        A3000
A3100        A3100    A3500
A3200        A3500               A3400
A3400        A3200                        A3500
A3500                            A3400    A3500
```

I am trying to make macro that will make hyperlinks in cells in columns K to N which will refer to cells in column E according to their value.

Comment: Ok, let us know how you get on with making this macro. If you run into any trouble, please put the code into your post, and let us know which issue you are facing. We would be happy to help.

Comment: I am really novice at visual basic & started learning about it.So, not getting anywhere to develop a code for this logic.

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service, but a place for people to get help with specific errors or unexpected behavior with code they have already written, I suggest you read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I concur with Plutian and Zack E's comments above, I enjoyed the quick exercise. I'm fairly new to VBA as well, so little exercises are helpful learning tools for me. Here's a macro I put together that seems to do what you're looking for:

```
Sub HyperlinkMacro()
    Dim cell, LinkRange, TargetRange As Range

    Set LinkRange = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:N5")
    Set TargetRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E5")

    For Each cell In LinkRange
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=Range("E1:E5").Find(cell.Value).Address, TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```